# Java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

При попытке обновить пользователя возникло исключение unsupported operation и null, при выводе пользователя в методе, где сохраняется пользователь все нормально, пользователь не налл, все выводится корректно. Проблема при обновлении именно с ролью, когда я обновляю юзернейм все нормально.

**метод из сервиса**

```
@Override
    public ChatRoom saveChatRoom(ChatRoomDto chatRoomDto, String authorizationHeader)
            throws EntityExistException, EntityNotFoundException, JwtTokenNotFoundException {

        if(chatRoomRepository.findByChatRoomName(chatRoomDto.getChatRoomName()).isPresent())
            throw new EntityExistException(chatRoomDto.getChatRoomName());

        ChatRoomUser chatRoomUser = tokenService.findChatRoomUserByToken(authorizationHeader);

        User user = userService.findUserByUsername(chatRoomUser.getUsername());

        user.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(roleService.findRoleByName(CREATOR.name())));

        userService.saveUser(user);

        return chatRoomRepository.save(
                ChatRoom.builder()
                .chatRoomName(chatRoomDto.getChatRoomName())
                .connectedUsers(Collections.singletonList(chatRoomUser))
                .build()
        );
    }
```

**user service**

```
@Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(Objects.requireNonNull(user));
    }
```

**ошибка в строчке с return userRepository.save(...)**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException] with root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
```

Comment: Запускали программу в режиме отладки и смотрели значения переменных? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: а полный стектрейс нельзя привести?